# MATLAB Beginner recursive functions

Tags: matlab, recursion

Just having a little difficulty with the syntax of matlab functions;

```
function f = fact(x)
    if x == 1
        return
    else
        f = 1 - x*(fact(x-1))
    end
end
```

When calling this function in the command window with the argument 10 I receive the error

```
Undefined function 'fact' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in recursion (line 6)
    f = 1 - x*(fact(x-1))
```

I've had a look around and solutions for the first revolve around the pathing of the m-file which doesn't seem to be a problem as other files in the same directory run fine,

The second I'm not sure why the error in line 6 occurs, my guess is it has something to do with the variable and function names.

As a side question, are both these `end` statements necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious error is your function filename.  You have a function called `fact` defined in your code but you named your file `recursion`.  Make sure that both your function name **and** the filename are **both called** `fact`.

If you were to name your file as `recursion`, then make the function name defined in your code as `fact`, this is what would happen if you tried calling your code:

```
>> f = recursion(10);

Undefined function 'fact' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in recursion (line 6)
    f = 1 - x*(fact(x-1));
```

... look familiar?

As such **make sure your filename and your function name are named the same**.  In fact, in the MATLAB editor, it should automatically give you an error saying that both of these are not the same.

---

There is also another error in your code.  The base case is not defined properly.  Always remember when you are writing recursive algorithms is that eventually the function is going to return... and that's when you hit the base case.  We can see here that it is when `x = 1`. When `x = 1`, you're supposed to assign something to `f` which is the output.  You are simply exiting the function, and so when `x` becomes 1, your code will spit out an error saying that `f` was not assigned when the function finishes.  As such, you need to figure out what your base case is.  I'm going to assume that your base case (when `x = 1`) is going to equal `0`.  You will obviously need to change this as I don't know what your code is actually computing.  Basically, you need to do this:

```
function f = fact(x)
    if x == 1
        f = 0; %// Base case needs to change according to your specs
    else
        f = 1 - x*(fact(x-1))
    end
end
```

---

When I do this, I get the following output when `x = 10`

```
>> f = fact(10);

f =

 1334961
```

---

I don't get an error when I run this code now.  Also, check to see if you have any variables named `fact` in your workspace.  When this happens, you are in fact **shadowing** over your function with a variable, so it is actually trying to access the variable called `fact` instead.  As such, try **clearing your workspace** by doing `clear all;`, then try this code again.

---

## One warning

If you were to specify x to be `0` or negative, this function will **never** stop.  As such, you need to provide some check and perform the proper action when this happens.  Also, you need to make sure that you specify what type of inputs are accepted for `x`.  Judging from the context, `x` are positive integers only.  As what @Glen_b has noted, should you provide any number that isn't a positive integer, this function will never stop as `x` will never equal 1 down the recursion pipeline.

## To answer your optional question

The first `end` statement is required to end the `if` statement.  The second `end` statement isn't required, but it's good practice anyway.  However, if you have multiple functions defined inside your function file, then yes it is most definitely required to properly signify that the end of that function is defined there.  However, you don't need it if you're only writing one function per file, but I would recommend keeping it there as it's good practice.

Comment: Perfect, well explained. I still get the errors when I run your bug-less script so the problem is on my end.
Thanks!

Comment: @sebajun - Make sure that your filename and the function defined inside the file are named **the same**.  In your output, it says that your file is named `recursion`.  Make sure you change this to `fact`.

Comment: @sebajun - I've also answered your optional question too!

Comment: Thank you both so much, works perfectly now. I'm a complete beginner in MATLAB and no one I asked at my uni would answer so thanks a lot.

Comment: @sebajun you're very welcome. To be honest most of my matlab knowledge comes from being self taught and experience. I've used it for quite a while. I'm glad I helped! Please consider accepting my answer too :-)