# quickselect code in matlab

Tags: matlab, tail-recursion

Let us consider following pseudo code

```
QuickSelect(A, k)
  let r be chosen uniformly at random in the range 1 to length(A)
  let pivot = A[r]
  let A1, A2 be new arrays
  # split into a pile A1 of small elements and A2 of big elements
  for i = 1 to n
    if A[i] < pivot then
      append A[i] to A1
    else if A[i] > pivot then
      append A[i] to A2
    else
      # do nothing
  end for
  if k <= length(A1):
    # it's in the pile of small elements
    return QuickSelect(A1, k)
  else if k > length(A) - length(A2)
    # it's in the pile of big elements
    return QuickSelect(A2, k - (length(A) - length(A2))
  else
    # it's equal to the pivot
    return pivot
```

I have wrote following code in matlab

```
function []=Quickselect(A,k);
% A-unsorted array
%k-we  want to return kth largest element
% let r be chosen uniformly at random in the range 1 to length(A)
i=1; %initialize index
j=1; %initialize index
n=length(A);%length of array
r=floor(1+(n-1)*rand);%random index
pivot=A(r);  % choose pivot  as  A(r);
A1=zeros(1,n);  %create additional  arrays
A2=zeros(1,n);%create additional  arrays
for m=1:n
    if A(m)<k
      A1(i)=A(m);
      i=i+1;
    else if A(m)>k
      A2(j)=A(m);
      j=j+1;
        end
    end
end
if k <= numel(A1)
  return Quickselect(A1,k);

    else if k > (length(A) - length(A2))
   return Quickselect(A2, k - (length(A) - length(A2)));
        else 
        return pivot;
        end
end
end
```

---

```
>> A=[2 1 4 3 6 5 7 9 8 10 11 13 21 12];
>> Quickselect(A,3)
Error: File: Quickselect.m Line: 23 Column: 10
Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

---

I dont understand reason of error, can't i use recursive property in Matlab? thanks in advance

Comment: possible solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048615/matlab-beginner-recursive-functions

Comment: In the `for` loop, you've replaced `pivot` with `k`. This is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's what's wrong with your code. I've already commented about replacing `pivot` with `k`, but after looking at the code more closely I found a few more errors. @AnderBiguri already identified a couple of problems, and I'll mention those here as well for completeness.

```
function []=Quickselect(A,k);
```

As Ander mentioned, you need the return value. I'm going to directly use `pivot`. And function declarations don't need a `;` after them. You're effectively creating a blank first line.

```
function pivot = Quickselect(A,k)
```

You had me confused for a second with the comments:

```
% A-unsorted array
%k-we  want to return kth largest element
% let r be chosen uniformly at random in the range 1 to length(A)
```

The pseudocode you gave actually finds the kth *smallest* element. In the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `1` would be the smallest element, `2` would be the second-smallest element, and `5` would be the fifth smallest-element.

```
i=1; %initialize index
j=1; %initialize index
n=length(A);%length of array
r=floor(1+(n-1)*rand);%random index
```

I don't know why you're not using `randi` here. Not actually wrong the way you're doing it, but it's much clearer, much more concise with `randi`.

```
r=randi(n);     % random index
```

Note the `% create additional arrays` portion here:

```
pivot=A(r);     % choose pivot as A(r);
A1=zeros(1,n);  % create additional arrays
A2=zeros(1,n);  % create additional arrays
```

These arrays are created with the same size as `A` and will always have the same size as `A`. This was addressed by Ander in his comment and will become very important later.

Now the `for` loop:

```
for m=1:n
    if A(m)<k
```

Your pseudocode says:

```
    if A[i] < pivot then
```

`pivot` is the value of the element chosen as the pivot and you're trying to split `A` into two lists: one with elements less than the pivot, and another with elements greater than the pivot. `k` is the *index* of an element whose value you're looking for. The pseudocode correctly uses `pivot`, so your code should be:

```
  if A(m)<pivot
```

The same thing goes for `A(m)>k`. It should be `A(m)>pivot`. Also, in Matlab, the keyword is `elseif`, with no space. I'm deviating a bit from my method of commenting on individual lines as they occur, but I wanted to leave the next section uninterrupted to point out something else.

```
      A1(i)=A(m);
      i=i+1;
    else if A(m)>k
      A2(j)=A(m);
      j=j+1;
        end
    end
end
```

See that first `end`? What does it end? It's better if you look at your whole code, but that last `end` ends the `for` loop. The second-to-last `end` ends the `if-elsif`. The first `end` is wrong and should be removed. Actually, and I'm very surprised Ander didn't mention this, but if you had properly indented your code you would never have created this bug. In fact, your entire code should be re-indented *consistently* for this reason as well as readability. The `for` loop section should look like this:

```
   for m=1:n
      if A(m)<pivot
         A1(i)=A(m);
         i=i+1;
      elseif A(m)>pivot
         A2(j)=A(m);
         j=j+1;
      end
   end
```

Now it's quite obvious what blocks the `ends` go with and how many we need.

The next line in your code is:

```
if k <= numel(A1)
```

This is the bug I referred to above that's mentioned in Ander's comment. `numel(A1)` will always be equal to `numel(A)`, because that's the way you created the array. Therefore, `k` will *always* be less than or equal to the size of the input array. (Well, it *should* be, but there's no explicit check for that in the pseudocode or your code, but oh well.)

So where do we get the number of elements actually added to `A1`? Well, we go back to that `for` loop where we were using `i` as the index of the *next* element to be added to `A1` and `j` as the index of the next element to be added to `A2`. This means that the valid length of `A1` is `i-1` and the valid length of `A2` is `j-1`. So your `if` statement should be:

```
   if k <= (i-1)
```

Next we have:

```
  return Quickselect(A1,k);
```

Ander Biguri also mentioned this one. Matlab does not return values this way; you simply set the value of the return variable that was defined in the function declaration. I used `pivot`, so we take the value returned from our recursive call to `Quickselect` and assign it to our copy of `pivot`. When the function ends, the value of this variable automatically becomes the return value.

Now for the parameters you're passing to the recursive call. I've already said that `numel(A1) == numel(A)`. So if you recursively call `Quickselect` on `A1`, you're not actually reducing the size of the array. We only want to pass the valid portion of `A1` and since we know that it has `i-1` valid elements, we can just take the first `i-1` elements, i.e. `A1(1:i-1)`.

The correct line is:

```
      pivot = Quickselect(A1(1:i-1),k);
```

Now we run into the length problem again, and you've switched from using `numel` to using `length`. Not actually wrong, as far as it goes, but bad style.

```
    else if k > (length(A) - length(A2))
   return Quickselect(A2, k - (length(A) - length(A2)));
```

This is always zero. The length of `A` minus the length of something that is the same length as `A` is zero. The *valid* length of `A2` is `j-1`. Also, we already know the size of `A`, it's `n` from way up there at the beginning. The corrected lines:

```
   elseif k > (n - (j-1))
      pivot = Quickselect(A2(1:j-1), k - (n - (j-1)));
```

And so we come to the end of our code:

```
        else 
        return pivot;
        end
end
end
```

As mentioned, return doesn't set any return value, it just returns from the function. Since we're at the end of the function anyway, there's no need to return. Once again, proper indentation would show you that there is an extra `end` here as well. We need one for the `if-elseif` block, and one to end the function itself, but the third one is extraneous.

If you make these changes you will have a working quickselect function.

Comment: ok my friend thanks very much,now i understood, code is working thanks,i am new in recursive implementation in matlab language ,so i have studied now,just about length of new arrays,i dont undertsand  it well,i will try to clarify

Comment: that is professional  explanation,that is how i am explaining my students  ,so detailed thanks @beaker

Answer (score 5):

It is not a recursivity problem, it is just wrong Matlab syntax.

In Matlab, return does not force the return of a variable, but just makes the function stop and get out. If you want to return something your function should begin with:

```
function [outvar]=Quickselect(A,k);
```

And every time you have a

```
return pivot;
```

or

```
return Quickselect(A1,k);
```

You should modify it by

```
outvar=pivot; % or outvar=Quickselect(A1,k);
return;
```

Comment: @datodatuashvili If you read carefully the answer you can see that I have told you how to change the code!

Comment: dont be angry my friend, i am getting this error: Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your
available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Comment: @datodatuashvili :) I am not angry! That error tells you that you went over the default recursion limit Matlab allows. If you use `set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) ` you can change the recursion limit to the value you set in N. It is important to have a recursionlimit in case you make an infinitely recursive algorithm. However, Matlabs advises you that if you go too far on N (amount of recursion calls) you can crash a computer with an error that is commonly known as `StackOverflow` (not kidding!)

Comment: ok but for good algorithm,it should not be,so that means  there is some  logical error in my code and i can't guess where it is

Comment: @datodatuashvili In your code, `length(A1)` and `numel(A2)` are alwais 14 both with the example you have. You need to go through you code bcause you are not using the functions correctly

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I've added your observations to my own in my answer so that all of the required fixes were in one place.

Comment: @beaker definitely I don't mind! Your answer is awesome,  keep with the good job!